# parsing a large xml string in java using XMLReader

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have the following bit of code which parses an XML string returned from from a database:

---

> > > XMLReader xReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
> > >
> > > xReader.setContentHandler(parser);
> > >
> > > xReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(**theResponseStringFromTheDatabase**)));

---

whenever the **theResponseStringFromTheDatabase** is too large, the parsing fails. Is there a way to modify the code so it will parse large strings?

best wishes,
ck

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to get a *[Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)* accessing that column.

`InputSource` can take a `Reader` object, and that reader should be one capable of pulling the XML incrementally (suitable for the SAX reader underlying the `XMLReader`)

[ResultSet.getCharacterStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getCharacterStream%28java.lang.String%29) may do the trick.

Comment: hi, thatks for your response. i think that the problem is that the whole xml is one very large tag

Comment: The code I am using the get the xml string from the database is this: 
String theResponseStringFromTheDatabase = (String) execute(request.getUrl(), new CallableStatementCallback() {

   public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement st) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    st.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CLOB);
    final String in = request.getUrl(params, null);
    st.setString(2, in);
    st.execute();
    
    return st.getString(1);
   }

Comment: I think you need the character stream returned, *not* the String